# Falt form(at com.going.books.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19))

Tags: java, android

//main activity.java

```
package com.going.books;

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ImageButton;
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //start button
    private Button startBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        //button start
        startBtn=findViewById( R.id.startBtn1 );
        startBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start Activity
                startActivity( new Intent( MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class ) );
            }
        } );
    }
   }
```

//complete
 //activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_uid"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layerType="software"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <!--complete-->
</LinearLayout>'''
```

//logcat error
    '''04-05 17:34:45.750 32139-32139/com.going.books E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.going.books, PID: 32139
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.going.books/com.going.books.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
            at com.going.books.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
            at com.going.books.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.going.books:drawable/custom_uid" (7f06005f)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06005f a=-1 r=0x7f06005f}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.(View.java:3738)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:498)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:200)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:196)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:192)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
            at com.going.books.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
    '''

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I am not used background image so no error will appear.
then I am using a background image then the onClick() method error will be produced.
Next than not using background image so no error will be found...
but I am not sure why did hear...

Comment: your problem in drawable resource file :" android:background="@drawable/custom_uid"" can you show this file(code)